# QGIS C++ Hello World example crashing

Tags: qgis, c++, qt

I have written a very simple C++/Qt application using QGIS comprised of a single "main.cpp" file as below:

```
#include <qgsapplication.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    QgsApplication app(argc, argv, true);
    return 0;
}
```

and my Qt Creator project file is defined as:

```
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = qgis_test
TEMPLATE = app

CONFIG += c++11

SOURCES += main.cpp

HEADERS  +=

LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib -lqgis_core

QGIS_DIR = /home/rouhollah/Programs/qgis-2.8.1

INCLUDEPATH += $$QGIS_DIR
INCLUDEPATH += $$QGIS_DIR/src/core

DEFINES += CORE_EXPORT= GUI_EXPORT=
```

The program is compiled and linked, but exits unexpectedly when run with the following error message:

```
realloc(): invalid pointer: 0x00007fc3d802e0e0
```

Even running the program in the Debug mode, the debugger stops before hitting the breakpoint at the first line of the `main` function.

Note that I have installed the QGIS libraries by compiling the source codes obtained from GitHub.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After hours of trying out whatever I could think of, I finally found out that QGIS is not compatible with Qt 5.4. Hence, I managed to run a sample program compiled and linked against Qt 4.8.6.